# pyspark: type object 'Row' has no attribute 'fromSeq'

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
z1=["001",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,30,41,42,43]
print z1
r1 = Row.fromSeq(z1)
print (r1)
```

Then I got error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-fa5cf7d26ed0> in <module>()
      2 z1=["001",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,30,41,42,43]
      3 print z1
----> 4 r1 = Row.fromSeq(z1)
      5 
      6 print (r1)

AttributeError: type object 'Row' has no attribute 'fromSeq'
```

Anyone know what I might have missed? Thanks!

Comment: I think what you want is https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html Not https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row

Comment: In pyspark documention there is no implementation of fromSeq

Comment: How do I create an Row from a list then? The array is big, I can't type the elements one by one

Comment: you can simply say Row(z1)

Comment: I did the following: z3 = ["a","b","c"]
r3 = Row(z3)
print (r3)  but get the error of TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found at types.py line 1292:  return "<Row(%s)>" % ", ".join(self)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide names just use `tuple`:

```
tuple(z1)
```

This is all what is needed to build correct DataFrame